# Directory look up failed with operating system error 3 ( System cannot find the file specifed)

Tags: sql-server, virtual-directory

I am getting below error when i try to create database with below error -
Directory look up failed with operating system error 3 ( System cannot find the file specifed). Create Database failed.

I am trying to create the database in D: Drive which is a virtual directory created using SUBST command. I tried giving full sql service account permissions to this directory but still failing with error. 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Finally was able to get rid of this error by using physical D: Drive instead of virtual drive.